# How is GetType implemented in every object in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I was looking at [object](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Object.cs) out of curiosity, and I realized that object doesn't have a get type method. Yet it's commonly stated that every object in the language can have `.GetType()` called on it.

Does everything actually inherit from Type instead of object? And if thats the case how does `typeof(object)` / `(object)val.GetType()` work?

Comment: I don't think that's the whole picture to be honest. Take a look at the [referencesource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,105).

Comment: Interesting that core's object is so much smaller. I looked through the repository for anything that was also a partial class of object and came up empty. Would this mean in Full Framework that the extern modifier is used to expose an implementation of get type via the type class? (That's pretty cool)

Comment: The compiler and CLR will do a lot of magic in order for us to treat certain objects a certain way even when it's not declared or implemented in the class/interface. Many times, a lot of the core internals are implemented as native code either within an external library or within the clr itself. Other examples of this magic is done for arrays and value types in particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found an article on the Internet written by Konrad Kokosa, which gives great explanation of how `Object.GetType()` works:
http://tooslowexception.com/how-does-gettype-work/

Here is the quote from this article, which should answer your question:

> If we look at the .NET Framework Reference Source method
>   Object.GetType(), it quickly turns out that there is nothing really
>   interesting:
>
> ```
> // Returns a Type object which represent this object instance.
> [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
> public extern Type GetType();
> ```
>
> Note that this method is not marked as virtual, but behaves like a
>   virtual – for each object returns the actual type. This is due to the
>   special, internal implementation. Attribute value of InternalCall
>   means that the method is implemented internally in the CLR. Thanks to
>   CoreCLR we can look deeper. If we want to find an internal function
>   implementation of InternalCall, we look at the CoreCLR’s source file
>   .\Src\vm\ecalllist.h where there is an adequate mapping. In our case
>   it is
>
> ```
> FCFuncStart(gObjectFuncs) 
>     FCIntrinsic("GetType", ObjectNative::GetClass, CORINFO_INTRINSIC_Object_GetType) 
>     FCFuncElement("MemberwiseClone", ObjectNative::Clone) 
> FCFuncEnd()
> ```
>
> And thus we come to an implementation (here and further I omit not
>   relevant code):
>
> ```
> // This routine is called by the Object.GetType() routine. It is a major way to get the Sytem.Type 
> FCIMPL1(Object*, ObjectNative::GetClass, Object* pThis) 
> { 
> // ... 
> OBJECTREF objRef = ObjectToOBJECTREF(pThis); 
> if (objRef != NULL) 
> { 
>     MethodTable* pMT = objRef->GetMethodTable(); 
>     OBJECTREF typePtr = pMT->GetManagedClassObjectIfExists(); 
>     if (typePtr != NULL) 
>     { 
>         return OBJECTREFToObject(typePtr); 
>     } 
> } 
> else 
>     FCThrow(kNullReferenceException); 
> FC_INNER_RETURN(Object*, GetClassHelper(objRef)); 
> } 
> FCIMPLEND
> ```
>
> In short, what we see here is getting so-called object’s MethodTable
>   (Object::GetMethodTable) and returning the corresponding Type object
>   (MethodTable::GetManagedClassObjectIfExists) or create it if one does
>   not exist (GetClassHelper)1). Here we should stop for a moment and for
>   clarity divide our discussion into separate steps.

Answering your "Does everything actually inherit from Type instead of object?" question - definitely not.

Comment: It seems like the author of this article is a SO user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2894974/konrad-kokosa :)

Comment: Thanks for the article, and great answer!